# HTTPS request break down

Tags: tls

when I hit 
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=101010101010
https://facebook.com/john.profile

can my ISP know what I am doing on facebook from my requests?
"/profile.php?id=101010101010"
"/john.profile"

or they can just know I browse [facebook.com] over HTTPS?

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, you want to know if a request made from the index.php file will travel over HTTP or HTTPS, given that you reached the index.php page from an HTTPS connection?

Comment: GET request is made from Client->Server asking for the "/home/index.php" over HTTPS

Comment: No, just when you have some GET-parameter in the request uri like index.php?path=...

Comment: so when I am

asking for the "/home/index.php" over HTTPS (domain.com)

I am just exposing an HTTPS request over domain.com
or the filepath too "/home/index.php" ?

Comment: Nothing is exposed here at least as the transport is encrypted using TLS.

Comment: Also see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/can-urls-be-sniffed-when-using-ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your ISP can not see this.

This was already answered here: [What information can my ISP see when I visit a website?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107065/what-information-can-my-isp-see-when-i-visit-a-website)

Comment: This is not correct, or is at least very misleading. GET parameters are encrypted.

Comment: You can still see them in logfiles even when you use HTTPS